# EF6でのPostgreSQLへの接続について

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

お力添えをお願いします。
初めてEF6を利用する者です。
下記コード実行時、LINQのところで、
接続用の文字列（connectionStrings）の定義が誤っているという旨のエラーメッセージが表示されます。
本当に誤っているのか、誤っているとすればどこかをご教示願います。

```
internal static class 画面01_Model
{
    internal static IEnumerable<User> GetItems(string keyword_)
    {
        using (DBContextUser db = new DBContextUser())
        {
            string searchWord = "";
            if (keyword_ != null) searchWord = keyword_;
            var result =
                from u in db.Users
                where u.Name.Contains(searchWord)
                select u;
            foreach (User one in result)
            {
                yield return one;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

環境／インストール済みパッケージ：
*PostgreSQL 9.4.5*
*Visual Studio Express 2015*
*Entity Framework：v6.4.4*
*EntityFramework6.Npgsql：v6.4.1*
*Npgsql：4.0.10*
*NUnit：3.12.0*
*NUnit.ConsoleRunner：3.11.1*
*NUnit3TestAdapter：3.16.1*

app.config（一部抜粋）：

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ＸＸＸシステム.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionPGSQL"
            connectionString="Data Source=192.168.x.xx;User ID=yyy;Password=zzz;Database=tamib;"
            providerName="Npgsql.EntityFramework;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
            <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql"/>
        </providers>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql"/>
    </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</system.data>
```

エラーメッセージ：

> 型 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' のハンドルされていない例外が
> System.Configuration.dll で発生しました
> 初期化文字列の形式が使用に適合しません。Index 0 で始まっています。

※「使用」は「仕様」の誤りと思われます
よろしくお願いします。

参考図書：
『ひと目でわかる Visual C# 2015 アプリケーション開発入門』伊藤 達也／著　日経BP社 日経BPマーケティング　2016.10

**【追記】**
指摘があったので、下記のようにconnectionStringを編集しましたが、エラーメッセージは変わりませんでした；

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ＸＸＸシステム.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionPGSQL" 
        connectionString="Server=192.168.x.xx;Port=5432;Username=yyy;Password=zzz;Database=tamib;"
        providerName="Npgsql.EntityFramework;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

また、この他にも Data Source（Server）の部分をHostに変更して試したりもしましたが、エラーメッセージは変わらず、
「初期化文字列の形式が使用に適合しません。Index 0 で始まっています。」でした。

**【追記２】**
下記コードにより、connectionStringを用いたPostgreSQLへの接続を試した結果、データ取得まで成功しました；

```
        string connString
            = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ＸＸＸシステム.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionPGSQL"]?.ConnectionString;
        var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
```

---

**【追記３】**
本記事後のエラー

> "The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql.EntityFramework;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details."

への対応を記載します。結論としては、app.configの記述誤りが理由でした；

connectionString の providerName属性の値を entityFramework>に合わせて、
"Npgsql.EntityFramework;"→"Npgsql"
（セミコロンは入力しない）
と変更することで、正常に動作しました。

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ＸＸＸシステム.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionPGSQL" connectionString="Server=192.168.x.xx;Port=5432;Username=yyy;Password=zzz;Database=tamib;"
        providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: あとは、postgreSQLかEntity Frameworkに動作確認用の単独ツール等があれば、それに作成した`connectionString`を指定して試してみるとかでしょうか？

Comment: さらに追記しました

Comment: connectionString そのものは間違ってはいなさそうですね。

Comment: そうだと思われます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 本当に誤っているのか、誤っているとすればどこかをご教示願います。

`DBContextUser` の コンストラクタの部分を確認願います。

```
public DBContextUser()
  : base("ＸＸＸシステム.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionPGSQL")
{
}
```

となっていれば動作すると思いますが base("＊＊") の `＊＊` の部分が 違っていると

```
var con = db.Database.Connection;
```

のように DB接続を取得するときに、

`「System.ArgumentException: '初期化文字列の形式が使用に適合しません。index 0 で始まっています。'」`
のエラーが発生しました。

接続文字列を取得する前の段階でエラーが出ているようです。

Comment: base("DefaultConnectionPGSQL") と記載しておりました。こちらの対応後、エラーメッセージが変わりましたので、こちらを回答とさせていただきます。

Comment: なお、次のメッセージは"The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql.EntityFramework;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details." です。対応不明の場合は質問を別に作成します。

Answer (score 0):

[接続文字列のエラーメッセージ](http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2012/07/24/error-message-for-conection-string.aspx)からの類推で「Index 0 で始まっています。」ということは先頭から間違っているらしいですね。

そこで検索したら先頭の`Data Source=`は`SQLServer`用で、`postgreSQL`では`Server=`になると思われます。
それから`Port=`のポート番号指定の不足でしょうか。
[EntityFramework 6（C＃）を使用してPostgreSQLデータベースに接続する](https://entityframework.net/ja/knowledge-base/37838170/)
[Set a connectionString for a PostgreSQL database in Entity Framework outside the app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39018552/9014308)
[PostgreSQL database connection in asp.net mvc and Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558564/9014308)

そして質問には書かれておらず対処済みかもしれませんが、`<providers>`や`<system.data><DbProviderFactories>`のセクションにも追加が必要なようです。

試してみてください。

---

ちなみに[The Connection Strings Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)というサイトがあって、Npgsqlの情報もあったのですが、特に不足しているようには見えませんでした。

Npgsqlのページはこちら
[Npgsql connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/)

---

そしてこちらの記事の方が上記紹介したサイトの元のようです。
内容は変わらないのですが、コメントで何か記述が増えています。
[Connect to PostgreSQL database using EntityFramework 6 (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838170/9014308)

こちらは解決していないけれど3つくらい回答が付いています。
[how to create postgreSQL database using EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19183855/9014308)

それから、こちらの記事の後半でデータベースコンテキストクラスでbaseにコネクションストリングを指定するとか、パラメータにスキーマ名を指定するとかの使い方が記述されています。
[Using PostgreSQL with Entity Framework](https://schneide.blog/2017/09/26/using-postgresql-with-entity-framework/)

何か参考になれば。

---

上記最後の紹介記事とか、@k systemさん回答とかの元資料になる記事がこちら。

[接続文字列とモデル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings)
[規則による接続とデータベース名を指定して Code First を使用する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#use-code-first-with-connection-by-convention-and-specified-database-name)
[App.config/web.config ファイルで接続文字列を使用して Code First を使用する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#use-code-first-with-connection-string-in-appconfigwebconfig-file)

Comment: 五月雨式にコメントに書くよりも、質問記事を編集して追記してみてください。あと使ったことが無いので細かいところは分かりませんが、変更した内容をビルドしてテスト・実行環境に反映されているのでしょうか？

Comment: 見づらいコメントを削除して記事本体を編集しました。少なくともconnectionStringについては、実行時のウォッチで変更の反映が確認できています。